# Best way to convey highly skewed data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, skewness

I am estimating a linear probability model with a hierarchical structure.  I am bootstrapping standard errors to test the significance of the coefficients in order to double check the parametric estimates of the standard errors.

In the bootstrapping process I am finding that the coefficients are all positive (which I expected) but there are a few extreme positive outliers. The outliers make the standard errors huge and subsequent t-statistics small. This is misleading because an empirical p-value has a value under 0.01.

My questions are

1. What is the best way to convey that this coefficient is statistically different from zero?
2. What would be the best way to report these results? Normally in a LaTex table I report coefficients plus standard errors.

Comment: Sounds like the assumptions of the t-test aren't met, so the p-values it would generate are irrelevant.